# SQL Order by grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a column `rating` with number 0 - 1000

I want to order these rows by `rating ASC` but I want that if the rating is between 0-99 they will have the same sorting order (same for 100-199, 200-299, etc). And these groups I want to have randomized when returned from the DB

Is this possible with SQL?

Example:

This is the initial table

[image]

this is the table after a regular order by rating asc

[image]

and doing the order with the groups of steps of 100, and then randomized

[image]

Comment: Show an example output please. Everything is possible in SQL.

Comment: Be more specific? An Example Output will be much appreciated

Comment: So, two rows with ratings of `199` and `150` may appear in the output in either order, but both should appear before a row with a rating of `206` and both should appear after a row with a rating of `70`?

Comment: I added an example process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide the ratings by 100 and then use `random()`:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  T
ORDER BY Rating/100,random()
```

Assuming that `Rating` is an integer, the division automatically truncates the result to also be an integer, thus handily treating `199/100` and `101/100` as both just being `1`.

Comment: will the random be on each group of rating?

Comment: @NickGinanto - each row will individually generate a random number and be sorted based on that, within each rating group.

Answer (score 0):

Probably try using offset

Example

SELECT rating FROM ratingtable ORDER BY rating ASC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;

this will display rating between 1-100

to display ratings between 101-200 just set the offset to 100

Answer (score 0):

don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve, but I think you should try using OVER PARTITION. Try this:

```
SELECT rating, userid, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY 100 ORDER BY rating ASC) FROM ratingtable ;
```